# Dealing with pending deletes when updating nuget packages in TFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, nuget

We have a Nuget package that has been developed in-house and adds a number of MVC-related assets to any project that pulls it in - an `Index.cshtml` view in the `Views\Home` folder, a `HomeController` and `Controllers` folder and a `Content` folder with some static files in (amongst others).

Every time we create a new version of the package and pull it into a project that is under TFS source control, the current version of the package is uninstalled first (standard Nuget behaviour). This causes all of the assets to be placed into the pending delete state within source control. Whenever a folder is emptied of all files, that folder is also placed into the pending delete state.

When the new version of the Nuget package is then installed, package manager throws up errors because the assets it is trying to copy over are already set to delete, or the parent is set to delete in the case of folders.

Is there a way to deal with this situation, either by forcing TFS to effectively undelete the assets when installing the new package or not to delete them in the first place when uninstalling?

Comment: We do have similar issues. It seems to be related to Local Workspaces and with a certain amount of files from the updated package, as one of our packages only contains two files and they are flagged correctly as  "changed" by our TFS.

So are you using Local Workspaces, too? How many files are included in your package?

Comment: I am using local workspaces too. There are 5 files in the package, 1 controller, 1 view and 3 other assets. The folders that each go into don't have any other files in them, so when the package gets uninstalled, the folder that the files are in is marked as pending delete. If a file that is part of the package is changed after installation, Nuget seems clever enough to ignore that (or at least give you the option to ignore it) and not remove the file. Those files are marked as modified within TFS.

Comment: So I take it that you did not stumble onto a solution, yet. That's a shame. ;) I actually resorted to converting my workspace back to a server workspace and do not have those issues anymore. Could be an actual NuGet bug? (See [this official issue](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1690), even though it was closed some time ago).

Comment: No, no solution yet. Cheers for the heads up about workspaces. That could be a workaround. I'd really rather not change back to a server workspace though if I can avoid it. Looks like that issue is still open but has no resolution. Ah, the joys...

Comment: Just found your question as trying to find a solution for the exact same problem. Any news on this topic?

Comment: Unfortunately not and I've left that contract now so may never get to the bottom of it - if you do find an answer, please post it here!

Answer (score 0):

While there are hooks and ways wherein you can handle this (hooking into `IVsPackageInstallerEvents` or managing it thru `init/install/uninstall.ps1` scripts, it is probably easier to use Nuget Package restore.

The recommended practice is to not checkin "packages" folder into your source control, rather use NuGet package restore to restore packages during builds. More info [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

Comment: Agreed. I always use package restore. The issue here isn't with the contents of the packages folder. It is with specific files that the package installs into a target project (not binaries but actual code files). Those assets must be checked into TFS because we have deployment builds that install the web project files onto target servers that would fail if those files were excluded from TFS.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? We have the same issue with our in-house developed NuGet package and an unmanaged DLL on which the package relies.

Comment: I've seen this problem with things like javascript, though.  These things don't end up in the package folder

Answer (score 0):

I do believe this has been fixed in the latest TFS/Visual Studio/Nuget combination.

So hang in there, there is hope.

However, for those of us still stuck on somewhat older versions, I found it easiest to remove the package entry from packages.config manually, then using nuget package manager to install (instead of updating) the newest version of the package, has the least side effects.